# Error connecting to SMTP server with c# .net

Tags: c#, ssl, smtp, smtpclient

I have a web service provider to host some .net sites that I run.  I was on their old platform and recently upgraded to a newer platform of theirs, and that included using a different smtp server.  I had no problem sending mail previously on the old host, but now when I send mail with SmtpClient, it throws an exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
```

The code is very simple (I've obviously obscured my smtp server, username, and password in this code example):

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mysmtpserver");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("myfromaddress", "mytoaddress");
client.Send(message);
```

Now, in what I believe is a related issue which may shed some light on the problem, is when setting up MS Outlook to use this same server, I had to change the configuration in the Outgoing Server settings in the Advanced tab because the old settings suddenly did not work:

(used to work, no longer works) Port 587, TLS encryption type

(this now works) Port 587, SSL encryption type

I'm not an smtp expert by any means, but it seems to me something isn't configured correctly on my hosting provider's server, but I don't know how to convey this.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but SSL used to be port 465, and TLS should be port 587, is that correct?  Am I misunderstanding something in regards to the SmtpClient class?  I mean, I've been doing this for years... or is it possible that my hosting provider doesn't have something configured properly on this new smtp server?